# jQuery UI dialog with validation on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to validate a select. This the select:

```
<select id="ccategory" name="category" class="input">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">[Choose Category]</option>
  <option value="Arts and entertainment">Arts and entertainment</option>
  <option value="Automotive">Automotive</option>
  <option value="Business">Business</option>
  <option value="Computers">Computers</option>
  <option value="Games">Games</option>
  <option value="Health">Health</option>
  <option value="Internet">Internet</option>
  <option value="News and Media">News and Media</option>
  <option value="Recreation">Recreation</option>
  <option value="Reference">Reference</option>
  <option value="Shopping">Shopping</option>
  <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
  <option value="World">World</option>
</select>
```

And this is the script to validate the select:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#dialog').validate({
    rules: {
      category: { required: true },
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
      alert('valid form'); // for demo
      return false; // for demo
    }
  });
});
```

This is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HmQZr/)

This function approves the submit's form also when I have the value of the select in `selected`

```
<option value="0" selected="selected">[Choose Category]</option>
```

How to change the script to not approve or validate the select when `value="0"`? Maybe, if possible, with a message near the select.

Message: "This field is required."

This is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CvKCY/1/) to validate on the first textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/CvKCY/2/)**

**JS/jQuery**

```
$('#dialog').validate({
    rules: {
        category:
        {
            required: true
        },
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        if ($('#ccategory').val() == 0){
            document.getElementById('choose_own_text').innerHTML  = "Please change here";
            return false;}
     //   console.log($('#ccategory').val());
        alert('valid form'); // for demo
        return false; // for demo
    }
});
```

I added `if ($('#ccategory').val() == 0){return false;}`, like this he checks if the value of the select is 0, and returns false to the submit.

**CSS**

```
#choose_own_text {
    display:inline;
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Ok.. I check you answer how accepted! Thank, but I can receive the you up-vote on my question?